# How do I redirect command output to a file?

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, hashsum

I have a command that I run in a folder that outputs MD5 hashes and filenames on the terminal:

```
ls |sort -nr | xargs md5sum
```

I need this output in a text file that I can download and compare to another folder on another customer's machine. How can I modify the command such that its output is stored in a file in say `/tmp`? I'm using Redhat 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It's a bad idea to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The primary job of `ls` is to list the attributes of files (size, date, etc.). The shell itself is perfectly capable of listing the contents of a directory, with [wildcards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29).

It's quite simple to run `md5sum` on all the files in the current directory and put the output in a file: [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) its output to the desired output file.

```
md5sum * >/tmp/md5sums.txt
```

If you want the output to be sorted by file name, [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) the output of `md5sum` into `sort`.

```
md5sum * | sort -k 2 >/tmp/md5sums.txt
```

Note that numeric sorting (`-n`) will only give useful results if the file names are purely numeric. If all you need is for the output to be deterministic, how you sort doesn't matter.

Comment: Let me give this a try tomorrow and report back.  My goal is to get the output from two supposed dirs on two diff servers and then do a diff on each file crossing my fingers they are the same. :)  Thanks.

Comment: @ZacAnderson If you have network connectivity between the two servers, there are easier ways to check that they're the same, e.g. `rsync -van /local/path remoteserver:/remote/path` (remove the `-n` to overwrite the remote files with the local files).

Comment: do I have to issue an ssh in there somewhere for the remote server or just put the IP in for the 'remoteserver'.

Comment: the command you noted above with the md5sum into the sort will work for me.  I had to put a space between the > and the / but it gave me the file, populated.  I will then take the file from server A and then from server B and do a diff on them to see if they are the same.  I'm nervous about the rsync command so I'm going to pass on that.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

output [redirecting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29#Redirecting_standard_input_and_standard_output) is done by below command

```
commandname > filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Same way as on most non-*nix platforms, actually.

```
somecommand > somefile
```

You don't need to sort it though, as `md5sum -c` will check the files for you.

Comment: I believe I tried this and it just sat and hung.  I broke out of the command and went to the folder I was sending the file to, /tmp, and no file exists with the name I gave it.  Here is what I typed: ls |sort -nr | xargs md5sum > /tmp/zac.txt