# How to create a file with pre-inserted text inside with bash?

Tags: bash

I want to make small bash scripts that will automate some stuff for me in new machines.

The only thing I still do manual is creating files with `vi` and pasting the text on the file.

How can I generate file X with "text i need here" inside it on bash? Without having to press enter, overwrite files if necessary and also create directories as needed?

Thanks

Example : Replacing a default sshd_config file with my version and creating a file with my public SSH key inside it. Generating another .sh file on-the-fly. Stuff like that.

Comment: Use Ansible or similar software to automate configuration and deployment on new and existing machines. I'm not sure what are you trying to do. Provide some examples please

Comment: `echo "text i need here" > some/file`?

Comment: If it's the redirecting to file part, see [How do I redirect command output to a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31331/how-do-i-redirect-command-output-to-a-file)

Comment: @muru well I do think that is a duplicate now :/ but I also feel my question will be easier found by people looking for something like this, and the answer is more noob friendly. Well whatever, thanks for the help tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For text content, the easiest, especially if the text contains multiple lines is to use a here-document. Add these lines to your script for instance for your script to create a `file.txt` with this text:

```
cat << 'EOF' > file.txt
Here is some text
or other
EOF
```

(you can use anything in place of `EOF` above as the end of file marker provided it doesn't occur in the text to insert. The first `EOF` has to be quoted to prevent any expansion inside the here-document).

For files with arbitrary content, you can use `uudecode`. It also lets you specify  the permissions for the file being created. For instance for a script to create a `foo` file with the content and permissions of `/bin/ls`, do:

```
(echo 'uudecode << "_EOF_"'
uuencode -m /bin/ls foo
echo _EOF_) >> your-script
```

Which will add the correspond code to your script. Something like:

```
uudecode << "_EOF_"
begin-base64 755 foo
f0VMRgIBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAMAPgABAAAAMFQAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAADD3AQAA
[...]
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
====
_EOF_
```

With the content of `/bin/ls` encoded in base64.

That assumes the `uudecode` is available on the machine you're going to run that command in. But that should generally be the case as `uudecode` is a POSIX command.

You can extend that to create several files by encoding a compressed tar archive:

```
(echo 'uudecode << "_EOF_" | gunzip | tar xpf -'
tar cf - file1 file2 file3 dir/file4 | uuencode -m -
echo '_EOF_') >> your-script
```

(assuming the target system has `gunzip` and `tar` (not POSIX commands but quite common)).

That also has the benefit of letting you encode additional file metadata like ownership or access and modification time (and more like ACLs and extended attributes, and hard link relationship with some `tar` implementations). It also allows you to easily create non-regular files like directories, symlinks, devices...

See also the [`shar` utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/manual/html_node/index.html) which can help you create portable self-extractable archives.

Comment: will this require a enter after pressing the button like the other answer?

Comment: @Freedo, I don't understand what you mean. This is about creating a script that creates some files with some content, I don't see where a key or button would come into the picture.

Comment: if I execute your echo command in the terminal just to test, it works, but it requires me to press enter after it to get me back to the terminal, will this behavior happen when executing the script? Also is there a way to make echo overwrite files and create directories as necessary? a example here http://imgur.com/a/H0LFg

Comment: @Freedo, `echo` outputs text; `>`, `<>` and `>>` redirections, `tar`, `uudecode` create files (`>` truncates them and opens at the start if they existed, `>>`  opens at the end and doesn't truncate, `<>` opens at the beginning without truncating); `tar`, `mkdir` can create directories.

Comment: I know about mkdir, I was asking more about making echo/cat create the directory if necessary so I don't need to create it before running it. in the screenshot I provided I had to press enter to go back to terminal, but it worked.

Comment: @Freedo, no, `echo` just outputs text. It doesn't create  any  file or directory. Like I said, if you want to create a whole directory structure, the easiest may be to use `tar`+`uudecode` or `shar`. It's also important to consider access permissions. For instance, a `.ssh` directory or private key should only be accessible by the user (if your script contains such a private key, it's also important to keep the script private).

Comment: I just change permissions after with chmod and chown, I think it's easier :p but thanks!

Comment: @Freedo, but leaves a window open during which the files are accessible. You can add a `umask 077` at the top of your script to make sure files are created by default with very restrictive permissions, which you then widen later  on with `chmod` if needed.

Answer (score 2):

A script could do

```
sudo mv /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.orig
sudo cp "$HOME/my_configs/sshd_config" /etc/ssh/
sudo chmod go-w /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

or

```
sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.orig
cat "$HOME/my_configs/sshd_config" | sudo tee /etc/ssh/sshd_config >/dev/null
```

to back up any old `sshd_config` and then install a new one.

I mean, it's just a matter of having a collection of files somewhere and then copy them to the correct locations and making sure that the installed files have the correct permissions. This could be automated with a script.

There are however specialized software for doing automatic provisioning and configuration management, such as Ansible and Puppet.

These types of software may become more interesting as soon as you need to set up more than a couple of machines.  We, for example, use Ansible to set up private Docker containers for our customers on our compute-cluster.

Comment: I don't want to transfer files to the machine before doing anything, it's way better to generate the files on-the-fly there. And those softwares are probably way beyond my needs. But thanks for the answer :D

Comment: @Freedo There's nothing stopping you from transferring a script and some files from somewhere to the machine and running the script there using `scp` and `ssh`.