# How to create a file with specific command to run in linux?

Tags: linux, touch

I would like to create a file with:
name:

```
Hyper
```

command run:

```
"/opt/Hyper/hyper" %U
```

or
name:

```
Google Chrome
```

command run:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --no-sandbox
```

( when we click in this icon,it would open Google Chrome)

or
name:

```
FileZilla
```

command run:

```
filezilla
```

"touch" command can help us to create a file, but I don't know how can I define command to run for every created files

this file is like desktop icon, or icons in menu bar ( or Application bar ) when we create icon in desktop with ln -s, we create a Symbolic Link but this is not basically our program link.

Of course, we can copy any program icons to another path but we don't know where is our programs basically.

I would like to create icon for my installed programs to other path for example when we open Application menu we can see leafpad icon and this icon name is:

leafpad
and command to run leafpad is:
leafpad %f

I would like to create any program icons like icons in Application menu to any folder that I need it.

I hope my explain was enough.

thanks ahead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a file with pre-inserted text inside with bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389001/how-to-create-a-file-with-pre-inserted-text-inside-with-bash)

Comment: Though https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84686/how-to-create-custom-commands-in-unix-linux is probably what you want

Comment: Do you want to run those commands from the shell (command line) or via your desktop environment (if so: which one are you using)?

Comment: @Philippos I would like to do it via desktop, like shortcut, but not exactly ln -s to create shortcut icon, i would like to create starter icon in every folder that i need for my linux programs, like firefox or chrome or metasploit or another programs,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that,
my problem resolve is:

create file like file.desktop
and write content like this within it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

this sample was for Sublime Text

we can use another samples to another programs like this

thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to create bash aliases; there's no need to create new files. Aliases can be added to your ~/.bashrc file, which is sourced every time you open a new terminal. For example, here's an alias for **Hyper**:

```
alias Hyper='/opt/Hyper/hyper %U'
```

To see the changes, re-source your ~/.bashrc, like this: `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: this is not what do i need, i need like shortcut icon, but this is not exactly shortcut with ln -s,  and I would like create them in every folder